# MonoDevelop Raspbian cannot load file or assembly 'MonoDevelop.Core'

Tags: c#, logging, monodevelop, raspbian

I'm developing right now a solution on Raspbian using MonoDevelop 4.0.12 in C# 4.0.

I have referenced MonoDevelop.Core in my solution (2.6.0, for the Logging mechanism in there). When I try to run the solution, I get an exception "cannot load file or assembly 'MonoDevelop.Core'". As far as I know, in Windows there are folders for each version of .NET and also a GAC, where all common libraries are stored.

If to suppose that the .NET 4.0 is working (Without this reference, the solution works. With it, not.) and on Linux there is no GAC, and in MonoDevelop Local Copy does not work (with the option selected and not selected same behavior), what is the solution? I mean, MonoDevelop.Core is a package reference as System from .NET is. Why the solution finds System, but doesn't find MonoDevelop.Core?

Comment: In the following post S_BatMan is pointing out, that the Mono runtime does not support .NET 4.0 on the Raspberry Pi. Have you tried to run the code with .NET 3.5?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547047/monodevelop-armv6-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: Can't add MonoDevelop.Core as a package assembly reference if I switch to .NET 3.5. It simply does not appear in the possible references. Anyway that post is old. .NET 4.0 is working, but MonoDevelop.Core is not found because some unknown reason.